# Accumulation point in a topological group of orthogonal matrices over R

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, diophantine-approximation

**I would like to ask your opinion on the point that looks simple.**

Consider the group of orthogonal matrices of order n over the field R of reals, equipped with the *topology induced by the Euclidean norm of matrices.*

Let g be one of such matrix and denote by X the topological closure of the cyclic group generated by g.

**My question:** May I find a matrix g with the property that:

*if the identity matrix I is the accumulation point in X of some sequence of powers of g, then the sequence is definitely trivial, that is, all the elements (except finitely many) equal I?*

*In other words,* can I exclude that, for a suitable g, the identity I is obtained as the accumulation point of a non trivial sequence in X?

I don't think such g exists but I'm not be able to exclude it with a direct argument.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Hi Freakish, Many thanks for your reply. I'll be a bit more precise. I'm searching for a rotation matrix g such that the cyclic group G of g is infinite (i.e. g is torsion-free) and in the topological closure of G the identity matrix is an isolated point. Does such g exist?

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff group (in your case the group of orthogonal matrices) and let $g\in G$. Of course $\overline{\langle g\rangle}$ is a compact subgroup of $G$.

If $|g|<\infty$ then $\overline{\langle g\rangle}=\langle g\rangle$ is finite and therefore the identity (and every other element of $\overline{\langle g\rangle}$) is isolated.

On the other hand, if $|g|=\infty$ then no element of $\overline{\langle g\rangle}$ can be isolated. That's because in general if a topological group has an isolated point then it is discrete. And discrete compact group is finite, but $\langle g\rangle$ is not finite. Therefore if $|g|=\infty$ then the identity (and every other element of $\overline{\langle g\rangle}$) can be approximated by non-constant sequence from $\langle g\rangle$.

An important example of those situations is with the group of rotations of plane, which is a subgroup of $O(2)$ topologically isomorphic to the circle group $S^1$. For a given real $r\in\mathbb{R}$ define $g_r$ to be the rotation by $2\pi r$ radians. Then $\langle g_r\rangle$ is finite if and only if $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. And if $r\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ then $\overline{\langle g_r\rangle}=S^1$.

Comment: Dear Freakish, Thank you very much again for your detailed explanation. It clarifies to me the point, completely. Best regards